# React app not locating .js files when deployed to custom domain with Google Cloud (GAE)

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, subdomain

I have a React app that I am trying to get running on a custom domain app.[customDomain].com with GCP. It can't locate the static files and I'm not sure why.

The react app is deployed as a service on Google cloud (not default, is second service in project). It functions perfectly with on the Google assigned URL (`https://[Service_ID]-dot-[Project_ID].ue.r.appspot.com/`). When running through a custom domain, index.html loads but none of the .js files are found (so result is blank screen) and give this error:

.js files error with 404

[image]

The other service in the project (is default and a Django API) serves on the same domain perfectly well and I am aiming for the React app to serve on a `app.` subdomain. To achieve this I have the following `dispatch.yaml`

```
dispatch:
- url: "www.[customDomain].com/"
  service: default

- url: "api.[customDomain].com/"
  service: default

- url: "app.[customDomain].com/"
  service: React-App
```

I suspect the problem is in `app.yaml` for the react app but I can't work out what needs changing. This is the current `app.yaml`

```
env: standard
runtime: nodejs14
service: React-App
handlers:
- url: /static
  secure: always
  static_dir: build/static
- url: /(.*\.(json|ico|js))$
  secure: always
  static_files: build/\1
  upload: build/.*\.(json|ico|js)$
- url: .*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: build/index.html
  upload: build/index.html
```

I have tried changing `"homepage"` in `package.json` but with no success.

Aside from the dependancies, the `package.json` contains:

```
"name": "React-App",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000",
```

Comment: Do you get any relevant information/errors in the logs during deploy? Can you try redeploying with the the verbosity flag set to debug to get more info (just add `--verbosity=debug` tp your command)? Also, what happens if you recreate your custom domain?

Comment: @RafaelLemos re-running deploy with `gcloud app deploy --verbosity=debug` the only thing that stands out is `DEBUG: No bucket specified, retrieving default bucket.`. Everything seems successful otherwise.

What do you mean by recreate custom domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue myself. The issue is in `dispatch.yaml`. The urls fields need to be `[subDomain].[customDomain].com/*`.

In current form it is an exact text match on URL only (with fall back to `default` service). This means the initial load of the page was hitting `React-App` service but the loading of resources was falling to the `default` service and so they couldn't be located. Adding `*` to the urls meant the resource requests were routed to the correct service.